# Are votes to a question comment more valuable than votes for an answer?

Tags: discussion

This may be a dumb question, but here goes.

I was looking at this question ([Convert a SQL Server datetime to a shorter date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901161/convert-a-sql-server-datetime-to-a-shorter-date-format)) and I noticed that **marc_s** made a comment to the question, which can be considered an answer. He got 3 votes for that comment.

A month later, **jabu.hlong** posted an answer with the same solution. He got 11 votes.

In my case, I ended up using `cast(getdate() as date)`, and I upvoted jabu.hlong's answer, even though I later noticed that marc_s had given the exact same useful reply as a comment instead of an answer.

More often than not, I look at answers to questions instead of comments to the actual question. And the votes received by both confirm that most users are the same way.

So why didn't marc_s post his comment as a question? Given his impressive profile, there has to be a reason why he chose that alternative.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you asking us?  Ask him why he did what he did.  You probably can't afford what I charge for the use of my mind reading device, so asking him instead of having us read his mind is probably going to be easier for you.

Comment: Answers should be answers, not comments.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  :D....

Comment: @Servy, given his SO profile, I thought more experienced users had a reason for that. That's all.

Comment: @rbhatup That's fine, but why didn't you *ask him* if  you wanted to know why he did what he did?  Why did you ask someone else to guess at why he did what he did, when he's the only person who can actually give you an answer?

Comment: How do I ask him? Do I go to his profile and PM him? I can't do that. Email? Call him? Chat?

Comment: Lighten up man, it's not my fault Christmas is over.

Comment: @rbhatup: I guess sometimes I find a "solution" to be so easy and simple it doesn't warrant being posted as an answer - a comment will do, so I add it as a comment. That's really all there is. Or in this case, from the question, it wasn't really clear what version of SQL Server he was using - so my response may or may not be applicable - so I just added it as a comment - not to give an answer that ends up not being applicable to a given situation

Comment: @marc_s, makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments are easily the lowest thing in any part of a question, or answer.  They're temporal; while they may provide useful context or pry into clarification on a question, they're not answers.  They're also not searchable.  They can also be deleted at a whim, and their votes scattered about the winds.

The chief thing that matters is the answer.  Even *if* a question is answered in a comment, **it should still be presented as an answer** so others may find it easier.

I'm willing to bet that the intent behind the comment was to narrow down possibilities to make it *easier* for someone else, or themselves, to answer.  As presented, there might have been ambiguity or a different approach between different versions of that database software which would have made answering it a fair bit more complicated.  Instead of forcing a would-be answerer to give an answer that accommodates two different answer versions, the comment was likely meant to force the user to specify which version they were asking about.

Comment: Spot on - as asked, the question was too open and unclear- I tried to get the OP to be more precise, and still provided what I believed was the most likely solution in the comment, too.